# Why jasmine fails to compare knockout.js observable objects but works with normal functions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, knockout.js, jasmine

I was writing jasmine test today and had to mock an knockout.js object result and to my surprise they were not equal although objects looked identical. After eliminating properties I narrowed it down to knockout.js observable. Below are two tests knockout one is failing while the one with function is successful.

```
(function() {

  var describe = window.describe,
    it = window.it,
    expect = window.expect;

  describe("Compare objects that have functions", function() {
    function AddIsExpandedProperty(recordObject) {
      recordObject.IsExpanded = ko.observable(false);
      return recordObject;
    }
    it("object that has knockout function", function() { // this fails
      var recordX = AddIsExpandedProperty({});
      expect(recordX).toEqual(AddIsExpandedProperty({}));
    });
    it("object that has normal function", function() { // this succeeds
        var func = function () { };
        var recordY = { f: func };
       expect(recordY).toEqual({ f: func });
    });
  });
})();
```

I was wondering why? Isin't knockout.js observables are mere functions?

1. One solution to this problem would be to create unwrapper that would be to unwraping all knockout.js observables and producing the unwraped objects. Then one could compare them to the mocked ones, but this would not be real a unit testing.
2. Other would be to use `.toBeTruthy()` instead of `.toEqual()` but this again is jeopardising the test - if those functions would be different test would pass.

**What solutions are there that would not require object modifications?**

I have also made a miserable attempt to [write jasmine test mock on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/sXFDCmbmnZBLBOxvDkWZ?p=preview)

Comment: An observable is a function, but not only a function. If you watch one in your browser you'll see knockout add plenty of stuff manage it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is natural that the two object returned from `AddIsExpandedProperty` are not equal.

The `ko.observable` function itself returns a **new** `function` instance every time you call it. So you can think about `ko.observable` as a constructor function so when checking strict equality two `ko.observable()` call never return the same object.

So your counter example is not testing how KO behaves, a more accurete example would be if your `func` returns a new function:

```
it("object that has normal function", function() {
    var func = function () { return function() {} };
    var recordY = { f: func() };
   expect(recordY).toEqual({ f: func() });
});
```

Of course this test case ialso fails like the KO one.

If you want to test object equality with `ko.observable` properties then I would suggest to use the `ko.toJS` to turn your KO observables to regular properties:

```
 it("object that has knockout function with toJS", function() {
   var recordX = AddIsExpandedProperty({});
   expect(ko.toJS(recordX)).toEqual(ko.toJS(AddIsExpandedProperty({})));
});
```

Demo [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0rJsWw6reHpHoh6dcY7q?p=preview).